# problems with accessing shared folder from ubuntu to ubuntu

Tags: networking, samba, file-sharing, shared-folders

I have samba installed on both ubuntu 14.04 machines, and they're are both connected to the same network.
+ I have apache installed on the desktop machine.
I made a shared folder in my home folder on the ubuntu desktop, but cannot access this folder from my ubuntu laptop(which is connected to the lan network by cable).

When I click browse network on my desktop machine(which is sharing the folder) I see 2 icons:
DESKTOP(which is my share) and Windows Network

However when I click browse network on my ubuntu laptop, I only see the Windows Network.

both machines have the workgroup "homenet" configured in the smb.conf file

any suggestions on what I could do?

Comment: I forgot to mention this: when i manually go to the path "smb://desktop/share" it shows me a popup login windows with homenet as domain, but no login combinations work to gain access, not even my desktop(owner of the shared folder)login credentials.

Comment: Have you run "smbpasswd -a USER" to set a SMB password?